# Access Callable after CancellationException exception of FutureTask.get

Tags: java

What's the prefered method to access the underlying Callable after a CancellationException exception of a FutureTask.get?

I have the following code -

```
public class Ping implements Callable
{
  public Ping(String serverName)
  {
    // stuff
  }

  // call() method, etc.
}

// other code

futures = executor.invokeAll(callables, TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

for (Future<Object> future : futures)
{
  try
  {
    PingStatus status = (PingStatus)future.get();
    // do stuff
  }
  catch (CancellationException e)
  {
    // HELP: throw new RuntimeException("Could not ping " + callable.serverName);  
  }
}
```

If the timeout is reached, and a CancellationException is throwing on the get, I'd like to throw a new exception that includes the serverName passed into the Callable. What's the best pattern here?  And, why doesn't FutureTask provide a reference to the underlying Callable passed in on the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Callable is not retrievable from the Future object due to the separation between the task and the result. There are many methods which would result in `Future` objects being returned that do not involve the use or creation of Callable objects. Take for instance the method `submit(Runnable task)` which takes a runnable instead.

Runnable and Callable do not share a common parent superclass meaning that if the future object were to give you the ability to retrieve it, it would have to return an object of type `Object`. And that is just plain ugly.

Fortunately, if you have read the documentation for the returned list in `invokeAll()` (emphasis mine):

> a list of Futures representing the tasks, **in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list**.

meaning that the order of the input collection of `Callable` to the returned list of `Future` is preserved. By this, you can use the current index of `Future` to work out which Callable was cancelled.

E.g:

```
futures = executor.invokeAll(callables, TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

int index = 0; // Index used for for-loop

for (Future<Object> future : futures){
    try{
        PingStatus status = (PingStatus)future.get();
        // do stuff
    }catch(CancellationException e){
        Callable<Object> offendingCallable = callables.get(index);

        // deal with object here 
    }

    index++;
}
```

As a side note, it seems like you are returning an object `PingStatus` as a result from the execution. You should thus declare your custom callable as:

```
public class Ping<PingStatus> implements Callable{
```

and your appropriate future objects as `Future<PingStatus>` to avoid nasty casts from `Object` to `PingStatus`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the same sequential order!